# How can I prove that $[1,2]$ is closed in $[0,4]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$[1,2]$ is closed in $[0,4]$  if $[0,4]\setminus[1,2]=[0,1)∪(2,4]$ is open. But $[0,1)$ and $(2,4]$ is neither closed nor open, right?

Comment: They are both open subsets of $[0,4]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong. The set $[0,1)$ is an open subset of $[0,4]$ since $[0,1)=(-\infty,1)\cap[0,4]$ and $(-\infty,1)$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R$. A similar argument shows that $(2,4]$ is an open subset of $[0,4]$.

Another way of seeing that $[0,1)$ is an open subset of $[0,4]$ is this: take $x\in[0,1)$ and let $r=1-x$. Then $(x-r,x+r)\cap[0,1)\subset[0,1)$. Again, a similar argument shows that $(2,4]$ is an open subset of $[0,4]$.

Comment: The thing is that according to his tags (which were present before his question was edited) he didn't study general topology yet. So the question that arises is how he defined open sets, because I don't think he knows what a subspace topology is.

Comment: @Theorem I've edit my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: I think OP should clarify what he's looking for rather than me, I don't think we can give a satisfactory answer without knowing his background.

Comment: You can also observe that $[1,2]$ is already closed in $\Bbb R$ and then it's also closed in any superset of $[1,2]$. A set $C \subseteq A$ is closed in $A$ iff there is a closed subset $C'$ of $X$ (the whole space, here $\Bbb R$) such that $C' \cap A= C$. So we can take $C'=C$ for your set. @Analysis

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I wasn't sure whether "general topology" would be an overstatement for the question... it's rather elementary.